# CSS space lines between spans

Tags: css, line, spacing

I have this structure:

```
<div class="gBigPage">
    <span class="gBigMonthShort">FEB</span><br />
    <span class="gBigDayShort">23</span><br />
    <span class="gBigYearShort">2011</span>
</div>
```

The gaps between the text lines are too big, I need them shortened so they are all virtually touching.

```
/* Mouseover div for day numbers */
.gBigPage{
    height:45px;
    width:30px;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-weight:bold;
    background-color:#ffee99;
    text-align:center;
    border-top:1px solid #c0c0c0;
    border-left:1px solid #c0c0c0;
    border-right:1px solid #c0c0c0;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:3;
}
.gBigPage:hover{
    cursor:pointer;
}
/* In the big day box, the month at top */
.gBigMonthShort{
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size:11px;
}
.gBigYearShort{
    font-size:11px;
}
.gBigDayShort{
    font-size:16px;
}
```

I can't do relative positioning for the spans, as there is a bug in Chrome which flickers the mouseover effect, pure CSS is the only thing that seems to work.

Fiddle for example:
http://jsfiddle.net/GmKsv/

Comment: Inline elements are a pain. It's so much easier if you [make your spans block-level](http://jsfiddle.net/GmKsv/12/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All you need is line-hight in your css. Add this to your `gBigPage`.

Here is the code:

```
.gBigPage{
    height:45px;
    width:30px;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-weight:bold;
    background-color:#ffee99;
    text-align:center;
    border-top:1px solid #c0c0c0;
    border-left:1px solid #c0c0c0;
    border-right:1px solid #c0c0c0;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:3;
    line-height: 13px;
}
```

Demo on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hart1994/GmKsv/15/)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, but the two gaps between the lines are no consistent

Comment: The gaps at the top and bottom?

Answer (score 1):

Use line-height in your css :) you can reduce the gap between lines

Comment: I tried line height, but each span needs it's own, when I put a line height in for a span it doesn't do much!

Answer (score 1):

Set each element's `line-height` style, e.g.

```
.gBigMonthShort { line-height: 10px; }
```

Comment: That doesn't work, I can set the line height for the entire div, but I need them different

Comment: Ah solved it, line-height in containing div does the BR height essentially, then I can line height individual elements

Comment: @Tom What do you mean? Each span already has a unique class name, so can't you style each one uniquely?

Comment: See answer below, I did it in the end but required 2 levels of line heights

Answer (score 1):

Tom, have you tried using CSS line-height?
[link text](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_dim_line-height.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Need to set 2 levels of line height, one in container and one for each span.

```
* Mouseover div for day numbers */
.gBigPage{
    height:45px;
    width:30px;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-weight:bold;
    background-color:#ffee99;
    text-align:center;
    border-top:1px solid #c0c0c0;
    border-left:1px solid #c0c0c0;
    border-right:1px solid #c0c0c0;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:3;
    line-height:4px;

}

/* In the big day box, the month at top */
.gBigMonthShort{
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size:11px;
     line-height:13px;
}
.gBigYearShort{
    font-size:11px;
     line-height:9px;
}
.gBigDayShort{
    font-size:16px;
    line-height: 13px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the `<span>`s block-level, and remove the line breaks:

http://jsfiddle.net/GmKsv/12/